# Typecast compojure route's id to integer automatically

Tags: clojure, routes, parseint, compojure, ring

I have something like this `(GET "/photo/:id/tags/:tag-id/...")`

and thus for every route inside that context I have to typecast these ids to Integer explicitly. Is there any way to achieve this automatically or have a common place to typecast ids instead of each controller's action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Compojure 1.4.0, you can also supply coercion functions for parameters using the :<< keyword:

```
[x :<< as-int]
```

In the above case, the parameter x will be passed through the as-int function before being assigned. If any coercion function returns nil, then the coercion is considered to have failed, and the route will not match.

Example:

```
(defroutes app 
  (GET "/customers" [] customers)
  (GET "/suppliers" [] suppliers)
  (GET "/accounts" [] accounts)
  (context "/statements" []
           (GET "/" [] statements)
           (GET "/:id" [id :<< as-int] (single-statement id))))
```

Answer (score 3):

You might get this behaviour using [compojure-api](https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api) where you can specify schema types for the URL/query params as well as request body. [For example](https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api-examples):

```
(defapi app
  (GET "/photo/:id" []
    :path-params [id :- Long]
    (ok {:message (str "Photo with ID " id)})))
```

By specifying `[id :- Long]` you ask to do a coercion of `id` path param to `Long` type.